# How to pass data from a child component to the parent component using Laravel and Vue

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I am using Vue.js 2 and Laravel 7.

I want to pass some errors from the child component to the parent controller. But for some reasons `emit` did not work.

This is the method of the child component **AllocateTask**:

```
    methods: {
        assignTask: function() {
            this.form.task_id = this.user.tasks;
            this.form.user_id = this.dev.id;
            alert(this.form.task_id);
            alert(this.form.user_id);
            axios.post('/ticketsapp/public/api/store_task_user', this.form)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
                alert('ok');
                this.errors = response.data;
                alert(Object.keys(this.errors).length);
                if (Object.keys(this.errors).length === 0) {
                    alert('viva');
                } else {
                    alert('noviva');
                    this.$emit('failure'); 
                    this.$emit('pass-errors', this.errors); 
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                alert('no ok');
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }
```

This is the parent component **TheReporterTickets**:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <allocate-task :dev="dev" :tasks="tasks" @pass-errors="onPassErrors" @failure="displayErrors=true" @success="displaySuccess=true"></allocate-task>
        <hr>
        <validated-errors :errorsForm="errorsTicket" v-if="displayErrors===true"></validated-errors>
    </div> </template>

<script>
    import AllocateTask from "./AllocateTask.vue"
    import ValidatedErrors from "./ValidatedErrors.vue"

    export default {
        components: {
            'allocate-task': AllocateTask,
            'validated-errors': ValidatedErrors
        },
        props: {
            dev: {
                type: Array,
                required: true,
                default: () => [],
            },
            tasks: {
                type: Array,
                required: true,
                default: () => [],
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.');
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                displayErrors: false,
                errorsTicket: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onPassErrors(value) {
                alert('error');
                console.log('errors passed');
                const values = Object.values(value);
                this.errorsTicket = values;
                console.log(this.errorsTicket);
            }
        }
    } </script>
```

As you can imagine, I am unable to call the method `onPassErrors` located in the parent component. I visualize correctly the alert in the `else` statement of the child component, so I suppose that I am unable to pass the data from the child to the parent component.
Can help?

Comment: Should work:  https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/trn1g95L/

Comment: But why my code does not work? I see the `alert('noviva')` located in the child component but I do not see the `alert('error')` located in the function `onPassErrors` of the parent component. Have you some ideas?

Comment: No, because the code and concepts you've shown work, so something else must be a problem.  Try removing things until your code is like my example, and add them back 1 by 1 until you identify the problem.